# C# Asp.Net 2.0 - How do I check a password against an active directory password?

Tags: asp.net, security, active-directory, asp.net-2.0, c#-2.0

I'm rewriting an internal application, which currently uses its own username/password combination. People are forever forgetting it, or not changing their password from the default, so I want to use single sign on and make use of our domain.

I am using .Net2.0 and I cannot find any ways of doing this outside of 3.5.

How can get the login name of the current user and then check an entered password against the password inside AD?

Comment: This article should serve as a good starting point: [Active Directory Authentication from ASP .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Also for sample try this [Everything In Active Directory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is also the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998360.aspx